# Why isn't $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x e^{-|x|}dx = 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} x e^{-x}$?

Tags: integration, functions

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x e^{-|x|}dx = 0$

$ 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} x e^{-x} = 2$

Isn't $xe^{-|x|}$ an odd function?

Comment: $x\mapsto x e^{-\lvert x\rvert}$ is odd, yes (and integrable). That is exactly why the integral is $0$; are you confused between even and odd? (What you are asking about would hold for an *even* function).

Comment: All your computations in your question are valid, so what makes you confused?

Comment: How can I delete the abs in the integral to solve it and get 0?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is an odd integrable function over the real line, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left( f(x)+f(-x)\right)\,dx = 0.$

Comment: Recall $|x|=x$ for $x>0$ and $|x|=-x$ for $x<0$. Much like @Jack has written.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is odd:
$$
(-x)e^{-|-x|}=-xe^{-|x|}
$$

so the area between the function and the $x$ axis for $x\in (-\infty,0]$ has  opposite sign of the area for $x \in [0,+\infty)$ and the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is null.

Comment: sorry, I edited my first post

Comment: OK, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.For odd functions $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=0$

2.For even functions $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_{0}^af(x)dx$

Since the funtion $xe^{|-x|}$ IS odd,according to no.1,you have $0$ as the answer.